# OpenSSL and Cryptography issue while trying to install a Python package

Tags: python, openssl, cryptography

Trying to run `make dev` on a python package and getting this log, any idea?

```
Using cached futures-3.2.0-py2-none-any.whl
    Building wheels for collected packages: cryptography
      Running setup.py bdist_wheel for cryptography ... error
      Complete output from command /opt/h/.venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lwPWQH/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpfQphoRpip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
      copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
      copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
      copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
      copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
      copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
      copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
      copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
      copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
      copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
      copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
      copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
      copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
      running egg_info
      writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
      writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
      writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      running build_ext
      generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
      generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
      generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
      building '_openssl' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
      build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
      compilation terminated.
      error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

      ----------------------------------------
      Failed building wheel for cryptography
      Running setup.py clean for cryptography
    Failed to build cryptography
    Installing collected packages: cryptography, zope.deprecation, peppercorn, deform, jinja2, deform-jinja2, urllib3, elasticsearch, functools32, greenlet, gevent, gunicorn, itsdangerous, jsonpointer, jsonschema, mistune, newrelic, oauthlib, passlib, pastedeploy, psycogreen, psycopg2, pyjwt, venusian, repoze.lru, webob, zope.interface, pyramid, pyramid-services, pyramid-authsanity, pyramid-jinja2, pyramid-layout, transaction, repoze.sendmail, pyramid-mailer, pyramid-tm, unidecode, python-slugify, raven, requests, requests-aws4auth, statsd, ws4py, wsaccel, zope.sqlalchemy, pyflakes, configparser, pycodestyle, mccabe, flake8, honcho, pep257, flake8-polyfill, pep8-naming, setoptconf, dodgy, wrapt, singledispatch, lazy-object-proxy, astroid, requirements-detector, futures, isort, pylint, pylint-plugin-utils, pylint-django, snowballstemmer, pydocstyle, pylint-celery, pylint-common, pyyaml, pylint-flask, docutils, pyroma, prospector, pyramid-mako, Pygments, pyramid-debugtoolbar, alabaster, babel, imagesize, typing, sphinxcontrib-websupport, sphinx, sphinx-rtd-theme
      Found existing installation: cryptography 2.1.4
        Uninstalling cryptography-2.1.4:
          Successfully uninstalled cryptography-2.1.4
      Running setup.py install for cryptography ... error
        Complete output from command /opt/h/.venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lwPWQH/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-f6jEfJ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/h/.venv/include/site/python2.7/cryptography:
        running install
        running build
        running build_py
        creating build
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
        copying src/cryptography/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
        copying src/cryptography/fernet.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
        copying src/cryptography/exceptions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
        copying src/cryptography/__about__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
        copying src/cryptography/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
        copying src/cryptography/x509/general_name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
        copying src/cryptography/x509/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
        copying src/cryptography/x509/name.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
        copying src/cryptography/x509/oid.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
        copying src/cryptography/x509/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
        copying src/cryptography/x509/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/x509
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/keywrap.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/multibackend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/interfaces.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/algorithms.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/modes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/totp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/hotp.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/twofactor
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/kbkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/concatkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/hkdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/pbkdf2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/scrypt.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf/x963kdf.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/kdf
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/padding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/interfaces
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/decode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/cmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/encode_asn1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dh.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ec.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/dsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hmac.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/backend.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/ciphers.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto/hashes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/backends/commoncrypto
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/_conditional.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl
        creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
        copying src/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto/binding.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/commoncrypto
        running egg_info
        writing requirements to src/cryptography.egg-info/requires.txt
        writing src/cryptography.egg-info/PKG-INFO
        writing top-level names to src/cryptography.egg-info/top_level.txt
        writing dependency_links to src/cryptography.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
        writing entry points to src/cryptography.egg-info/entry_points.txt
        reading manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
        no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/_build'
        warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'vectors'
        writing manifest file 'src/cryptography.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
        running build_ext
        generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_padding.c'
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
        generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_constant_time.c'
        generating cffi module 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c'
        building '_openssl' extension
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build
        creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
        x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.o
        build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_openssl.c:2:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
        compilation terminated.
        error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

        ----------------------------------------
      Rolling back uninstall of cryptography
    Command "/opt/h/.venv/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-lwPWQH/cryptography/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-f6jEfJ-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /opt/h/.venv/include/site/python2.7/cryptography" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-lwPWQH/cryptography/
    Makefile:68: recipe for target '.pydeps' failed
    make: *** [.pydeps] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing python headers (install the appropriate *-dev* package on debian-based linux or *-devel* on the redhat-based one), or the building process searches for them in the wrong place. In the latter case, either correct the building tools or override the header search path with various CFLAGS variables.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @drookie. The python headers are coming with the python-dev on Ubuntu, I have the newest version:
`python-dev is already the newest version (2.7.12-1~16.04)`

Comment: How to find out where the building process is searching for those packages?